# Drag and Drop item above components

Tags: css, drag-and-drop

I'm developing a drag and drop functionality from a side menu to a list.

I have 2 problems:

1 - When I drag the the item from the side menu, the item is displayed only on the side menu, when I move the mouse outside of the side menu it's not displayed (On the image number 2).

- I know it's something related to the z-index but I'm not being successful in applying it.

2 - I could successfully drop in the area once I was playing with the position, etc in the developer tools, but now it's not working and I'm struggling to find out where I applied the property and which was the exact property.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - When I drag the the item from the side menu, the item is displayed only on the side menu, when I move the mouse outside of the side menu it's not displayed (On the image number 
I know it's something related to the z-index but I'm not being successful in applying it.

R -

```
.sidebar-container {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

2 - I could successfully drop in the area once I was playing with the position, etc in the developer tools, but now it's not working and I'm struggling to find out where I applied the property and which was the exact property.

I had duplicated javascript on my screen. I don't know what was happening due to that, but after removing the duplicates, it worked.